# Full Calendar - events refetching but not rerendering

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have been playing with Full Calendar and have it bringing in events from a database. When it initially renders them, it checks if they were stored as an all day event or not and sets allDay to true or false depending on the result.

This works perfectly, but when a new event is dropped on to the calendar it is supposed to refetch all of the events and then rerender them so that they don't all default to allday events. However, although the refetch is being called, the rerender on the line after it is not. If i do call the rerender line in my browsers console, however, it rerenders them all perfectly to how they should be.

So I guess my question is, why would fullcalendar be refetching the events but ignoring the rerender? and is there a workaround for this?

Many Thanks in advance. My code is:

Initial rendering of events:

```
editable: true,
events: "json-events-log.php",
eventRender: function(event, element) {
            if (event.event_type_id==2) {
                element.addClass("red-event");
            } else if (event.event_type_id==3) {
                element.addClass("blue-event");
            } else {
                element.addClass("green-event");
            }

            if(event.all_day == 0){
                event.allDay = false;
            } else {
                event.allDay = true;
            }

        }
```

And the success function that is called after successfully posting the event through AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "new_event.php",
              data: ajaxData,
              success: function(data) {
                  if (data.moved==true) {
                    alert('success');

                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("rerenderEvents");


                    $("#updatingCal").addClass("hiddenUpdate");
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {

                        $(this).remove();
                    }



                  } else {
                        $("#updatingCal").addClass("hiddenUpdate");
                        console.log('fail');
                    }

              },
              dataType: "json"
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying the event data within the eventRender callback. You should modify the data within the eventDataTransform callback instead!

Answer (score 0):

You need cache your jquery selector for calendar in variable - `var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar();`. And when you render calendar need add this code:

```
if(calendar){
    calendar.fullCalendar('destroy');
}
calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    //your options
});
```